# How to read data corresponding to current date from Sqlitedatabase into setText

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**this is my DatabaseCreator.java file**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseCreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.myapp/databases/people.db";
   private static String DB_NAME = "people.db";
   private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
   public static String DATABASE_TABLE = "people_table";
   public String temp = "";

   private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
   private final Context myContext;

   public DataBaseCreator(Context context) {
       super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
       this.myContext = context;

   }


   public void openDataBase(String date) throws SQLException {

       // Open the database
       String myPath = "/data/data/com.example.myapp/databases/people.db";
       myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
               SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
       passText(date);

   }

   public final String passText(String date) {

       Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null,
               null, null, null);

       cursor.moveToFirst();

           temp += cursor.getString(1); 
       return temp;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }



}
```

**and this is my Activity6.java file**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Activity6 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String > listItem;
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;

    ListView userList;




    DatabaseHelper db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_6);

        TextView textView;
        TextView textview2;
        textView = findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
        textview2 = findViewById(R.id.textViewsecond);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        int currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int currentday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

       String arr[]= {"January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August","September","October","November","December"};

        String str1 = Integer.toString(currentday);
        String str2 = arr[currentmonth];
        String str3 = Integer.toString(currentyear);

        String str4 = str1 + " "+ str2 + " "+ str3;
        

        DataBaseCreator myDbHelper = new DataBaseCreator(this);

   

        myDbHelper.openDataBase(str4);

        textView.setText(String.valueOf(str4));

        textview2.setText(myDbHelper.temp);



        
    }






}
```

**my database contains :**

1st column - id , 2nd column - date , 3rd column - a task

**the output I require:**

the date I have passed as str4 ( which is also the value of the second column in the database) has to be used to  fetch the task from the 3rd column (I'm trying to do this in passtext()  )

Please help

Comment: Why not write a proper Sql query using "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ..."?

Comment: Thanks! It worked with the select ..where..from  :)

Comment: also when I give this:     ` int num = 1;
       String data = Integer.toString(num);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM people_table WHERE ID = 'data'", null);
        return cursor1;   => there is nothing returned in cursor 1 , whereas when I give ID=1 the corresponding row is returned.  Please help

Comment: Read the documentation for how to handle parameters in queries.